# Issue with code build pushing artifacts back to github

Tags: git, maven, ubuntu, ssh-agent, aws-codebuild

I am trying to run maven release:prepare with aws code build and getting an error saying that

```
The git-push command failed.
Command output:
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

tried passing public and private keys as well , which didn't work either 
is there a way to push code back to github with github user name and password instead of ssh keys

Answer (score 2):

It seems the `ssh` client is not installed or available on your PATH when running AWS CodeBuild. Try adding a command at the beginning of your build to install `ssh-client`. For example if you are using Build Spec something like:

```
...
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      ...
      - apt-get update -y
      - apt-get install -y ssh-client
      ...
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify if you have ssh installed and make sure it's within your search path?

Comment: looks like ssh isn't running on it .. 
    - ps -aux | grep ssh
returned nothing 
looking for a way to install it on ubuntu

Comment: you can follow the steps from below link to enable the SSH on ubuntu. http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/enable-ssh-ubuntu-16-04-lts/